# CSS Animation that Allows Image to Cover All Content on Screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how I can write a CSS animation that allows an image (id: slam) to suddenly appear on screen and cover all of the content without displacing any of the text. So far, this is what I have: 
HTML:

```css
    body{
     height: 100%;
    }

    div{
     overflow: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slam-animation {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transform: scale(10);
        }

        100% {
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(1);
        }
    }

    #slam {
        -webkit-animation-name: slam-animation;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
```

```html
 <body>
        <img id="slam" src="assets/images/Undesirable.jpg" alt = "undesirable">
      <header>
       <h1>Text</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="main_game">
       <p>Stuff</p>
   <div class = "col-xs-2">
   </div>
   
   <div class = "left_box col-xs-4">
    <p>Stuff</p>
   </div>

   <div class = "right_box col-xs-4">
    <p>Stuff</p>
   </div>

   <div class = "col-xs-2">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _**cover all of the content without displacing any of the text.**_

Comment: Right now the image pushes the text in the header and divs down. I want the image on top of them.

Comment: maybe you just need to set the `position: fixed` to the image, and set both its `width` and `height` to `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` to your image.

Using **absolute** position the element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout i.e. it will not affect the position of other elements.

> [*Reference Link to understand position **absolute***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main_game div {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slam-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(10);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(1);
  }
}

img#slam {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#slam {
  -webkit-animation-name: slam-animation;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img id="slam" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="undesirable">
  <header>
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="main_game">
    <p>Stuff</p>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    </div>

    <div class="left_box col-xs-4">
      <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right_box col-xs-4">
      <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```